# Updating env variables and parameters via a task in a job in gocd

Tags: go-cd

In GOCD we are able to define env variables and parameters for the entire pipeline, stage and individual jobs. Is it possible to update those already defined env variables and parameters via a task in a job when running the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to update them permanently or just for specific execution?

If you would like to do first, I suppose you have to work with config xml, using [Pipeline Config REST API](https://api.gocd.io/current/#pipeline-config).
For latter case you can [trigger pipeline](https://api.gocd.io/current/#scheduling-pipelines) with given environment variables set.

In any case, I would recommend you [yagocd](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd) library, which would let you do both tasks with ease.